# Why am I getting an ipfs resolve error when I reload my webpage

Tags: reactjs, ipfs

I am experiencing an error on my website where if I reload my page on something that is not just websiteName.com/ it will give me an ipfs error. This error more specifically
"ipfs resolve -r /ipfs/bafybeibun6ls5mzxo3btvco7rhjkgnws22fjzqrzqddagle6zsgadd2kmu/singleWatchView/5EKFc6CVM3236asxHx92: no link named "singleWatchView" under bafybeibun6ls5mzxo3btvco7rhjkgnws22fjzqrzqddagle6zsgadd2kmu"

This is my code in my App.jsx file

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <main className='App App-header'>
        <NavBar />      
        <WatchBrands/>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
              <Route path='/createWatchListing' element={<CreateWatchListing />} />
              <Route path=':searchedWatch' element={<SearchedWatches />} />
              <Route path='/singleWatchView/:watchId' element={<SingleWatchView />} />
              <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} /> 
              <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} /> 
              <Route path='/account/:accountId' element={<YourAccount />} />
            </Routes>
      </main>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I haven't tried that much to fix it because I am very unsure of what to fix